# Querying JSON and retrieving values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a JSON file mystatsjson.js that is of the following format:

```
var myJSON = [
  {
    "ProdID": 204,
    "Title": "The best basket in town",
    "FB": 32,
    "Twit": 45
  },
  {
    "ProdID": 201,
    "Title": "The best soap in the whole of US",
    "FB": 23,
    "Twit": 0
  },
  {
    "ProdID": 103,
    "Title": "Limited quantity only",
    "FB": 12,
    "Twit": 3
  },
  and so on]
```

I want to write a jQuery function that receives an ID parameter, matches it against the ProdID of myJSON and retrieve the numbers for FB and Twit for that ID.

Once done, it populates the following `<span>` in this HTML with those numbers. The value of "FB" will get populated in the span of fblink, and the value of "Twit" will get displayed in the span of twitlink :

```
<div class="displ">
    <a class="button__link" id="fblink" target="_blank" aria-label="">
      <div class="button--small"><div class="button__icon">
        <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px">
            <g>
                <path d="M19"/>
            </g>
        </svg>
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="button__link" id="twtlink" target="_blank" aria-label="">
      <div class="button--small"><div class="button__icon">
        <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px">
            <g>
                <path d="M23"/>
            </g>
        </svg>
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this. Also, how do I supply a default value for FB and Twit incase the ID does not have a match in myJSON?

Here's what I am thinking but have no idea.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
     var clone = $(".displ").clone();
     // query my json file
     clone.find("#fblink").find("span").html(myJSON.FB);
     clone.find("#twtlink").find("span").html(myJSON.Twit);
     $(".displ").append(clone);
});
```

Comment: @Olian04 Fair point. Added what I have tried so far. Was embarrassed to share, hence didn't add it the first time.

Comment: You should always show us what you've tried, it helps us understand where your problem is. Also, you don't ever have to feel embarrassed to share code on stackoverflow. We were all new at some point, and we have all made mistakes before. The entire point of SO is to help each other, if someone's rude then flag them and the community will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks @Olian04 for the words of encouragement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myJSON = [
  {
    "ProdID": 204,
    "Title": "The best basket in town",
    "FB": 32,
    "Twit": 45
  },
  {
    "ProdID": 201,
    "Title": "The best soap in the whole of US",
    "FB": 23,
    "Twit": 0
  },
  {
    "ProdID": 103,
    "Title": "Limited quantity only",
    "FB": 12,
    "Twit": 3
  },
]
$(document).ready(function(){   
          var clone = $(".displ").clone();
          var MYJSON = myJSON.find((elem)=>elem.ProdID=="103")
          // query my json file
        debugger;  clone.find("#fblink").find("span").html(MYJSON.FB);
          clone.find("#twtlink").find("span").html(MYJSON.Twit);
          $(".displ").html(clone);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="displ">
    <a class="button__link" id="fblink" target="_blank" aria-label="">
      <div class="button--small"><div class="button__icon">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="button__link" id="twtlink" target="_blank" aria-label="">
      <div class="button--small"><div class="button__icon">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Check if this is what you were trying to do. I added prodID ==103 for test.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will try this out and let you know if I face any issues.

Comment: @IWantToLearn did you get chance to look

Comment: Thanks so much mate. Your solution worked perfectly well. Marked as answer.

Comment: Happy to help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the right object from `myJSON` by filtering the array on the `ProdID`.
You can then use the code you had to append the data to the DOM.

```js
var myJSON = [{
    "ProdID": 204,
    "Title": "The best basket in town",
    "FB": 32,
    "Twit": 45
  },
  {
    "ProdID": 201,
    "Title": "The best soap in the whole of US",
    "FB": 23,
    "Twit": 0
  },
  {
    "ProdID": 103,
    "Title": "Limited quantity only",
    "FB": 12,
    "Twit": 3
  }
];

function getData(id) {
  return myJSON.find(e => e.ProdID === id);
}

function addToDOM(elem) {
  var clone = $(".displ").clone();
  clone.find("#fblink").html(elem.FB);
  clone.find("#twtlink").html(elem.Twit);
  $(".displ").append(clone);
}


const data = getData(201);
console.log(data);

addToDOM(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="displ">
  <a id="fblink" target="_blank"></a>
  <a id="twtlink" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using pure **`javascript`**, no need to use **`jQuery`**. You have to compare the value of entered id to the object **`ProdID`** value and you can set **`DefaultValue`** if ID match not found like below

```js
var myJSON = [{
    "ProdID": 204,
    "Title": "The best basket in town",
    "FB": 32,
    "Twit": 45
  },
  {
    "ProdID": 201,
    "Title": "The best soap in the whole of US",
    "FB": 23,
    "Twit": 0
  },
  {
    "ProdID": 103,
    "Title": "Limited quantity only",
    "FB": 12,
    "Twit": 3
  }
]

function matchData(ProductID) {
  var item = document.getElementById("displ");
  var cln = item.cloneNode(true);
  document.querySelector("#main").appendChild(cln);


  var MYJSON = myJSON.find((elem) => elem.ProdID == ProductID);
  //console.log(MYJSON);
  if (MYJSON != undefined) {
    cln.querySelector("#fblink span").innerText = MYJSON.FB;
    cln.querySelector("#twtlink span").innerText = MYJSON.Twit;
  } else {
    //console.log("Sorry ID not found");
    cln.querySelector("#fblink span").innerText = "Default Value";
    cln.querySelector("#twtlink span").innerText = "Default Value";
  }
}

matchData(203);
matchData(201);
matchData(204);
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

#displ {
  background: grey;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
}

#main #displ:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="displ">
    <a class="button__link" id="fblink" target="_blank" aria-label="">
      <div class="button--small">
        <div class="button__icon">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a class="button__link" id="twtlink" target="_blank" aria-label="">
      <div class="button--small">
        <div class="button__icon">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```